# call global function from setTimeout which is in if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have written a normal function named as 'row'. I have one more function name 'foo' and in that function i have written if condition and in that if condition i have written setTimeout.

I have tried making setTimeout in a function and then i have called inside if condition. Then also i am getting the same error. That row is undefined.

```
rows() {
  alert("Hello Row");
}
foo() {
    if (a == a) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          this.row();
        }
      }
    }
```

So my question is how i will call my 'row' function inside setTimeout?

Comment: Why are you using `this.row()` ?

Comment: Show your actual code...

Comment: value `this` will be different inside that function. You will need to save the reference of this in some variable and then access function through that.

Answer (score 1):

Functions must be declared with the `function` keyword.

Your `setTimeout` syntax is incorrect.

You don't need `this`.

You are calling a function named `row` when it should be `rows`

```js
var a;

function rows() {
  console.log("Hello Row");
}

function foo() {
  if (a == a) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      rows();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a [lexical scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```
foo() {
var that = this;
    if (a == a) {
      setTimeout(function() {
          that.row();
        }
      }
    }
```